# Categorical data seperate means

Tags: python, statistics

Hi there I am somewhat new to Python and thought the best way to learn it was to attempt my University SAS and R projects in Python. However, I am struggling to produce summary statistics of categorical data.[My data frame  is different bird species and their lengths.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DX7S.png) I am trying to get separate means for each species using something like 'WREN_AVG = df['WREN'].mean() but that does not work and I cannot seem to find a solution.

I am currently using numpy, matplotlib, pandas and seaborn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try :
`df.groupby('SPECIES')['LENGTH'].mean()`

Details :
the `groupby()` function lists all species found in the column `'SPECIES'` then you apply `mean` on the column `'LENGTH'`